# Excel - count days in each month between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an excel formula which can be dragged across a row of cells to give the number of days in each month between two specified dates.  E.g:

```
         A           B         C       D       E       F 

1  | START DATE | END DATE |  Jan  |  Feb  |  Mar  |  Apr  |...
   ---------------------------------------------------------
2  |  10/02/17  | 15/03/17 |   0   |  19   |  15   |   0   |...
```

An added complication is that  the end date may be left blank indicating that the end date should be treated as today. I can put a formula in the cells starting from C2 but columns A & B must be left for user entry.

I made some progress using lots of nested if statements  but am having real trouble getting it to handle if the end date is blank.

Can anyone help with this please?

*Edit

I refrained from showing the formula I had written so far as I'm afraid it's a bit messy but as it has been requested, I have now shown below (this formula from C2)

```
 =IF(AND($A2<C$1,$B2<D$1),DAY(A2),IF($A2>=D$1,0,IF(AND($A2<C$1,$B2=""),IF(TODAY()<C$1,0,IF(TODAY()>C$1,IF(TODAY()<D$1,DAY(TODAY()),D$1-C$1),IF(TODAY()<D$1,INT(TODAY()-$A2),$D1-$C1))),IF(AND($A2>=C$1,$B2=""),IF(TODAY()<D$1,INT(TODAY()-$A2+1),D$1-$A2),IF(AND($A2>=C$1,$B2<D$1),$B2-$A2+1,IF(AND($A2<C$1,$B2<C$1),0,IF(AND($A2>=C$1,$B2>=D$1),D$1-$A2,IF(AND($A2<C$1,$B2<D$1),DAY(B2),IF(AND($A2<C$1,$B2>=D$1),D$1-C$1,0)))))))))
```

Comment: If the first day counts, your example should have 19

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, the first day should count, I've edited my question

Comment: Also are we allowed to assume start date is no more than a year before end date?

Comment: Yes, the start date will only start from the beginning of this year

Comment: Well it'd be useful to see the formula you have so far; but just at a guess, replace every occurence of `[End Date]` in your formula with `IF(ISBLANK([End Date], TODAY(), [End Date])` should handle the blanks. Or a formula I like to use if `[End Date]` is some complex function rather than a cell reference (like in the IF statement above) is `1/IFERROR(1/[End Date], 1/TODAY())` as this only uses `[End Date]` once as opposed to twice in the other formula (but it's arguably less readable). It's always better to post the code you've written rather than just to try and get users to write it for you

Comment: Hi Greedo, thanks for the comment. I've tried a find and replace but I'm getting an error message saying I've entered too many arguments. Sorry, I could've shown the formula I have but I'm afraid it's quite a mess. I have about 20 nested if statements and I think it would just confuse things. I'm happy to post if you really think it will help though

Comment: Should be `IF(ISBLANK([End Date]), TODAY(), [End Date])` - missed off a `)`. A side note is that in the past I've found `ISBLANK()` a little unreliable - as the cell may appear empty but contain whitespace or a ' etc. So you may need to tweak the condition depending on what's working (e.g. try coercing to a number with `*1`)

Comment: I honestly think it would, there's a lot of clever people on this site who can read pretty much any formula, give it a go! But try to limit what you post only to show what's relevant (see [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also consider `IFS(` (office 365 2016) when using multiple nested if statements, or `CHOOSE(` if `IFS` isn't an option

Comment: I've shown the formula. I also tried the find and replace you suggested and it has accepted it has a valid formula which is great. Some of the figures still aren't correct but I suspect that's my own fault for making some error in the conditions, I'll have a go with IFS and see if that's easier. Thanks!

Comment: There's also this sort of approach =MAX(0,MIN($B2,DATEVALUE(D1&"-17")-1)-MAX($A2,DATEVALUE(C1&"-17"))+1) but haven't got time to post it right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyway here is the alternative approach for completeness based on the standard formula

```
=max(0,min(end1,end2)-max(start1,start2)+1)
```

for the overlap between 2 date ranges which gives

```
=MAX(0,MIN(IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2),EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(C$1&"-17"),0))-MAX($A2,DATEVALUE(C$1&"-17"))+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, I gave it a try earlier but was tired for not finding `EOMONTH`.

Comment: Thanks, my original effort used the next month instead to get the last day, but I realised this would fail when it got to December...

Comment: lol, exactly what made me give up. Never heard of `EOMONTH` before. Good you had found it finally :) BTW I think it is the correct way to go because it avoids large array computations.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Efficient and beautifully simple! I hadn't heard of EOMONTH either but good to know

Comment: for whatever Excel reasons, you might need to use semicolon `;` instead of comma `,` to separate operands in the formulas. Also, you should add `01` to make sure to compare the 1st of the month as `start2`, as in `DATEVALUE("01-"&C$1&"-17")`

Answer (score 4):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),B2))),"mmm")=C$1))
```

This will iterate through the days and match the text of the three letter month to the headers.

This assumes that the header is text and not a date that is formatted `mmm`.

The `ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & $B2))` is as close to a For Loop that we can get with formulas.  It will iterate 1 day at a time.  Because dates are stored as numbers in excel with one day being `1` we can iterate from the start date to the end date.

The SUMPRODUCT is an array type formula, it is what causes the formula to loop and does the count.

The `(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),B2))),"mmm")=C$1)` returns TRUE/FALSE for each iteration, while the `--` converts that to 1/0.

The SUMPRODUCT then adds all the 1/0 to get the count.

[image]

---

If the headers are dates formatted as `mmm` then use this instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),B2))))=MONTH(C$1)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works brilliantly, thank you. I've never used sumproduct before, I will familiarise myself with how it works. This is so much simpler than what I was trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Super answer - but to solve the edge case where column B value is empty, you can amend you formula to: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A4 & ":" & IF($B4="",DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW())),$B4))),"mmm")=E$1))` which just replaces $B2 in your answer with `IF($B4="",DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW())),$B4)))`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie or just wrap the whole in `IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & $B2)),"mmm")=C$1)),"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner - that leaves blanks when I try it out. I think the OP is looking for `if B = empty then B = NOW()` logic.

Comment: Missed that part but it can be shortened to `IF($B2="",TODAY(),B2)`