# Count the number of days in each month between two dates that span two different years

Tags: google-sheets

First time asking a question here so please forgive me. I am trying to count the number of days in each month between two dates. I have found an answer on here that solves this. However, it breaks down and gives me "0" as a result when the beginning date is in December and the end date is in January.

This answer by Tom Sharpe is the closest that I have been able to get to this answer. [Tom's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499098/excel-count-days-in-each-month-between-two-dates/44507544#44507544?newreg=09f89d33ed0544a4a38522df672580d7)!

I wish I knew how to format code or screenshots on this website. I'm sorry! The link to the question has everything, I just need it to work when the Date Range spans two different years.

Please let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the previous answer and it seems to work just fine for me.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B$2))),"mmm")=C$1))
```

I tweaked it a small amount, making the B2 from the original post an absolute value. I took this under January in cell C2 and handle dragged to fill in to December and everything calculated just fine even over multiple years. My initial thought is that your headings (jan-dec) have something that isn't a 3 letter abbreviation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was originally using Tom's answer in that postr which used MAX and EOMONTH. I went back and used your formula and got my spreadsheet to work. I don't know what I did wrong when I tried the SUMPRODUCT solution before, however I AM SO HAPPY it worked now. Thank you so much Ive been going nuts over this!