# Excel - count WORK days in each month between two dates

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out the number of workdays between two dates for each month. I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499098/excel-count-days-in-each-month-between-two-dates) already and it works just fine for the days.

I would now like to know, how many workdays there are in each month. Meaning (again based on the linked answer), I'm here:

[image]

and would like to get to this here:

[image]

Comment: You probably will need to count WEEKDAYS in your formula. However, this will not account for holidays which can get complicated because days off are not on the holiday itself if it falls on a weekend.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `Networkdays`. You can find details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) and [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-workdays-between-dates). You will need to know which holidays you have in-between.

I usually generate a list of all dates in a calendar year (or download it) and then mark the holidays I want to exclude with an x.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `NETWORKDAYS` function.

Based on the linked result, something like the below should work (and be easy to modify based on how your sheet is set up):

```
=IF(
IF(C2$3>$B2, NETWORKDAYS(B$2+1, $B2), NETWORKDAYS($A2, C$2)-SUM($B3:B3))<0,0,

IF(C2$3>$B2, 
NETWORKDAYS(B$2+1, $B2), 
NETWORKDAYS($A2, C$2)-SUM($B3:B3)))
```

For example:

[image]